# how to delete data in tableview, coredata, firebase database, the order of deleting?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, core-data, firebase-realtime-database

i am using table view which store data, and i upload these data in firebase and then save them in coredata

i want to delete a row in table view, here is the code:

```
let x = tableViewUsers![indexPath.row].permUser!
refDelete.child(emailReceived).child("Permission").child(x).removeValue()

self.tableViewUsers?.remove(at: indexPath.row)

self.TrackMeTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

//self.TrackMeTable.reloadData()

DataController.deletePermUser(emailAddress: tableViewUsers![indexPath.row])
```

what are the right order of these line codes, as i get error when i delete for the second time in first line of code with index out of range

Answer (score 0):

After you delete and item the number of items changes, that is why sooner or later you will get an error when deleting rows, because index will be out of bounds. What I suggest is after you delete row, update the tableview. `self.TrackMeTable.reloadData()`.

Comment: when i put the reload data line code, i found that it delete one raw and the other raw with empty value?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because after

```
self.tableViewUsers?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

the item at this particular index path does not exist anymore and the next call of `indexPath.row` raises an out-of-range exception if it was the last item.

Apart from the issue declare `tableViewUsers` as non-optional to get rid of all the exclamation and question marks

---

To solve the issue keep a reference to the user before removing it from the array

```
let x = tableViewUsers[indexPath.row].permUser!
refDelete.child(emailReceived).child("Permission").child(x).removeValue()
let user = tableViewUsers[indexPath.row]
self.tableViewUsers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.TrackMeTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
DataController.deletePermUser(emailAddress: user)
```